# How to identify which row to delete in mysql

Tags: html, mysql

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS degree (
    userId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    university VARCHAR(100),
    degree VARCHAR(30),
    field VARCHAR(100),
    graduation INT UNSIGNED,
    PRIMARY KEY (userId, university, degree, field, graduation)
);
```

There I collect degrees for users. And I have a user interface to insert a data into this table:
[image]

And I also have a "Remove degree" button on this interface but I don't know how to identify which row to delete in the `degree` table when user deletes some degree on UI.
Maybe I have to add `id` row to my table and when user updates degrees I have to get all ids of degrees for this user from the table and then delete these rows that don't exist anymore?

Comment: Your primary key is (userId, university, degree, field, graduation) which means all of this information is needed to uniquely identify a row. Instead add an authenticating primary key. Then pass that value to your UI in the from of a hidden field. When you click removed degree check the value and just remove the corresponding row. Will follow with example in a few.

Comment: typo authenticating = auto incrementing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your primary key is (userId, university, degree, field, graduation) which means all of this information is needed to uniquely identify a row. Instead add an auto incrementing primary key. Then pass that value to your UI in the from of a hidden field. When you click removed degree check the value and just remove the corresponding row.

Create your table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS degree (
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    userId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    university VARCHAR(100),
    degree VARCHAR(30),
    field VARCHAR(100),
    graduation INT UNSIGNED,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Create a Hidden Field to store the row ID where #### is the value of your rows generated by your back-end:

```
<input type="hidden" id="rowID" value="####" />
```

OR if you do not want to use and ID:

```
DELETE FROM degree
WHERE userId = '####'
AND university = '####'
AND degree = '####'
AND field = '####'
AND graduation = ####;
```

After reading your follow up about the question I would not have the remove button actually delete the degree from the UI. I would have it just hide the degree and set a value that degree was deleted.

```
<input type="hidden" id="deleted" value="false" />
```

Then change this value from false to true and you should have everything you need to know.